# Swift - Use regular expression to match word without underscore take so much time?

Tags: regex, swift

I'm using swift, and i really don't know why when i use \w to match word character. It also includes the underscore.

Here is my pattern to match last for words.

I have to use `([^\\W_]+)` instead of `\w` because i don't want to match underscore.

But the trouble is in the long string, it takes almose 20 seconds to execute.

Here is the code

```
var bs = "MIAMI — After 11 adversarial debates, the two chief antagonists to Donald J. Trump on Thursday night largely abandoned their strategy of brutally attacking him, choosing instead to use their final face-off before next week’s round of big Republican primaries to project gravitas and champion conservative positions on trade, jobs and Israel."
Regexp("((\\b([^\\W_]+){1,15}\\b)([\\s]+)?){1,4}\\z").matches(s)?.last
```

But the pattern:

```
Regexp("((\\b\\w{1,15}\\b)([\\s]+)?){1,4}\\z").matches(bs)?.last
```

Only need 0.009.
What's happening here? And how to fasty match word character without underscore?

Comment: What is `bs`??? And please try `\\b[^\\W_]{1,15}(?:\\s+[^\\W_]{1,15}){1,4}\\z`.

Comment: I've fixed the question with bs example string. Your pattern matches 5 words, not 4, and it takes 10 times slower than my second pattern

Comment: Well, one thing is certain: it is catastrophic backtracking. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ1oT6/2) here. You need to unroll the regex, to take out the nested quantifiers into a linear pattern sequence. What are the *requirements*? `([^\\W_]+){1,15}` makes no sense to me as you ask to fetch 1 or more letters or digits 1 to 15 times.

Comment: Here is your [second regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC4hF3/1), it looks OK. So, why not just replace `\\w` with `[^\\W_]`? Like `((\\b[^\\W_]{1,15}\\b)(\\s+)?){1,4}\\z`?

Comment: *5 words, not 4* - because I forgot to change `{1,4}` to `{0,3}` (the first part is separated from this repetitive group). Try `\\b[^\\W_]{1,15}(?:\\s+[^\\W_]{1,15}){0,3}\\z` if the words separated with whiespace are to be between 1 and 15 chars long.

Comment: It sounds like XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?